# JQuery Ajax call stop refresing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following html code:

```
<div>
    <form id="ChartsForm">
        <div id="optionsheader">
            <p>Choose your page:</p>
            <div id="dateoptions">
                <p>Until date: <input type="date" name="until_date" value="Until date"></p>
                <p>Since date: <input type="date" name="since_date" value="Since date"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <select name="accmenu" id="accmenu" style="width:300px; float:left; clear:both;">
            <?php
            $user_accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts','GET');
            foreach($user_accounts['data'] as $account) {
            ?>
                <option data-description="<?php echo $account['category'] ?>" data-image="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $account['id']; ?>/picture" value="<?php echo $account['id'] ?>"><?php echo $account['name'] ?></options>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <div class="insightsoptions">
            <p>Choose your insights:</p>
            <input id="newLikes" class="insightsbuttons" type="submit" name="submit" value="Daily new likes">
            <input id="unlikes" class="insightsbuttons" type="submit" name="submit" value="Daily unlikes">
        </div>
        <div class="insightsgraphs">
            <div id="dailyNewLikes"></div>
            <div id="dailyUnlikes"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

which has a form with the `id=ChartForm` that contain two date inputs `until_date` and `since_date`, one select `accmenu` and two submit inputs with the values `Daily new likes` and `Daily unlikes`. I use the following Jquery function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#accmenu').change(function() {
        $(".insightsgraphs div").hide();
        $(".insightsoptions input").attr("class","insightsbuttons");
    });
    $("#newLikes").one('click', function () {
        $.ajax({type:'GET', url: 'newLikes.php', data:$('#ChartsForm').serialize(), success:
            function(response) {
                var json = response.replace(/"/g,'');
                json = "[" + json + "]";
                json = json.replace(/'/g,'"');
                var myData = JSON.parse(json);
                var myChart = new JSChart('dailyNewLikes', 'line');
                myChart.setDataArray(myData);
                myChart.setSize(960, 320);
                myChart.setAxisNameX('');
                myChart.setAxisValuesColorX('#FFFFFF');
                myChart.setAxisNameY('');
                myChart.setTitle('Daily New Likes');
                myChart.draw();
            }});
        return false;
    });
    $("#newLikes").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
        $('#dailyNewLikes').toggle();
    });
    $("#unlikes").one('click', function () {
        $.ajax({type:'GET', url: 'unlikes.php', data:$('#ChartsForm').serialize(), success:
            function(response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#dailyUnlikes").html(response);
            }});
        return false;
    });
    $("#unlikes").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
        $('#dailyUnlikes').toggle();
    });
});
```

for the application flow in the following manner: every time I click on one of the input submit buttons the script will make only one Ajax GET request to a specific php file that send me back a response with which I create a Chart in a hidden div with the `id=dailyNewLikes` or `id=dailyUnlikes` by case (for testing purposes I work for the moment only on the first button). The button it will change his background color into green and the div it will be shown. I use `$("#newLikes").on('click', function(){` for change back and forth the background color and the display time of the div. (from green and `display:block` to red and `display:none`, you get the point I hope :D). Also I use `$('#accmenu').change(function() {` to change all buttons to red and hide the respective div in case an option from the select is changed. My problem is that after I refresh the page (Ctrl+R) choose since and until date, click on the first button (it change to green and the div is shown, also the toggle is working fine) and then click on the second button which works fine on the first click (is becoming green and div is shown) but on the second click I have an issue: the script is making another Ajax GET request (a wrong URL one) and the page is refreshed. Ex. of a good reguest URL:

```
http://localhost/smd/unlikes.php?until_date=2013-05-01&since_date=2013-04-01&accmenu=497232410336701
```

and an ex. of a wrong request URL:

```
http://localhost/smd/?until_date=2013-05-01&since_date=2013-04-01&accmenu=497232410336701&submit=Daily+unlikes#_=_
```

Like it can be seen (it doesn't need in the first to make this extra request) the php file is not present and also a new submit parameters is added. This also happen if I change from the select with another option. What am I do wrong? I really need to know, not just to have my code "fixed". It bugging me for a little while. Any feedback is more than welcomed. P.S. Also, how can I start the `.one` function only if both date inputs has been choosen? Something like how could help me?

```
var until = $('#dateoptions input[name="until_date"]').val();
var since = $('#dateoptions input[name="since_date"]').val();
if (until == "" || since == "") {
    alert('Until date or Since date missing!');
    return;
}
```

it will work that way? Sorry for the long question...

Comment: use `addClass()` to add a class not `attr()`..

Comment: @bipen thanks for the advice, I've changed `attr("class","insightsbuttons")` with `addClass("insightsbuttons")`

Comment: Add return false; at the end of your button click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should make your question a little shorter and just point what you need and  what errors are you getting ..anyways...going through your code i see you have two click event for same button at the end for `$("#unlikes").one` and `$("#unlikes").on(`..and `no return false` in other function.

try adding return false

```
$("#newLikes").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
    $('#dailyNewLikes').toggle();
    return false;
});

$("#unlikes").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
    $('#dailyUnlikes').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

my guess is that , since you have two click event..when it gets clicked ..these event will fire and since you are missing `return false` in second click function...the form gets submitted hence refreshing the form.

however its better if put your codes in single click function than creating two seperate click event.

Comment: Thank you very much for guidance. I've tried like you said for both button and now the first div is remaining hidden but the second is shown. But the biggest issue now is that if I press the second time on any button the page will refresh because it sends again a wrong URL Ajax GET request...

Comment: make sure you are adding this in both `var $this=$(this);` before ajax function call...

Comment: i think i missed something in my code.. but anyways.... try adding return false to both of the click event in your code and check that should work... i mean `$("#unlikes").on('click', function(){...return false})`

Comment: it works like this, great! Thank you. Now if I want to send a request when I change an option from the select how can I do that? Can you give me some guidance of probably what I should use?

Comment: welcome...not to confuse other user ...i am gonna change my answer first.... :)... so it helps other visitors too...

Comment: hmm and for you question you can call ajax request inside the change event of select... `$('#accmenu').change(function() { ..//call ajax here  }) ` ...